# How to drag and drop on click of element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on jquery drag and drop. I have some images in my sidebar.user can drag the images in from sidebar and can drop then in dropable div.drag and drp is working fine. But now i need that when user will click on any (image/item) in sidebar then that image will be dropped in dropable div automatically. i have created a function of drag and drop. i am tryig to call this funtion onclick of sidebar images but its not working.Any idea how i can do this.This is my code to drag and drop images.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

     makemedragable();
});

function makemedragable()
{
    var x = null;
    jQuery(".get-image .drag").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    tolerance: 'fit',
    revert: true,
    start: function (event, ui) {
        jQuery(this).prop('onclick', '');
    }   
    /* stop: function (event, ui) { ... } */

});
//jQuery(".droppable .drag").draggable({ });

    jQuery(".droppable").droppable({
        accept: '.drag',
        activeClass: "drop-area",
        drop: function (e, ui) {
            if (jQuery(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {

                x = ui.helper.clone(); 
                ui.helper.remove(); 

                jQuery("#droppable .resize-img").removeClass("mycurrent");
                x.addClass("mycurrent");

                jQuery("#droppable .resize-img").css({"display":"inline-table"});
                /* To show Controls first time on Dragged Image*/
                var droppedItemId = ui.draggable.attr("data-item-id");
                jQuery(".controls ").attr("controls-item-id",droppedItemId);
                jQuery("#droppable").find(".ui-resizable-handle").hide(); // To show Controls
                jQuery(".controls").show();
                dragEl        = jQuery(this); 
                stopPosition  = dragEl.position(); 
                var height = x.height();  // To show the controls with exact position
                var width = x.width(); //alert("stoppos"+stopPosition+"leftpos"+leftPos);
                var topPos = ui.position.top;
                var leftPos = ui.position.left;
                var mytop = topPos+height;
                var myleft = leftPos + width /2; 
                    //alert("left"+leftPos);        
                jQuery(".controls").css({"top": mytop , "left":myleft, "display":"block"});

                x.draggable({   
                    helper: 'original', 
                    cursor: 'move',
                    containment: '#droppable',
                    tolerance: 'fit',

                    drop: function (event, ui) { 
                        jQuery(ui.draggable).remove();

                    },
                    drag: function() {

                    },
                    stop: function() {

                        jQuery("#droppable .resize-img").removeClass("mycurrent");
                        x.addClass("mycurrent");
                        dragEl        = jQuery(this);
                        stopPosition  = dragEl.position();
                        var leftPos =    dragEl.position().left; 
                        var topPos =     dragEl.position().top; 
                        stopOffset  = dragEl.offset();
                        document_id   = dragEl.data("document-id");
                        signer_id     = dragEl.data("signer-id");
                        var height = x.height();
                        var width = x.width();
                        var mytop = stopPosition.top+height;
                        //var myleft = stopPosition.left + width /2; 

                        jQuery(".controls").css({"top": mytop , "left":myleft, "display":"block"});

                        dataItem = jQuery(this).attr('data-item-id');
                        jQuery("#droppable").find(".ui-resizable-handle").hide();
                        jQuery(".controls").hide();
                        jQuery(this).closest(".drag").find(".ui-resizable-handle").show();
                        jQuery(".controls").show();
                        jQuery(".controls ").attr("controls-item-id",dataItem); 

                    } 

                }); 

                x.resizable({
                    maxHeight: jQuery('#droppable').height(),
                    maxWidth: jQuery('#droppable').width(), 
                    aspectRatio: true,
                    helper: "ui-resizable-helper", 
                    handles: "nw, ne, sw,se" 
                });  

                //x.addClass('remove');

                x.appendTo('.droppable');


            }
        } 
    });

/* To remove the Element on remove click */
jQuery("#droppable .controls li.canvas-remove-item").on('click', function (e) 
{
    var removeId = jQuery(".controls").attr("controls-item-id");
    //jQuery('#droppable .resize-img').filter('[data-item-id = '+removeId+']').remove();
    jQuery('#droppable .mycurrent').remove();   
    jQuery("#droppable").find(".ui-resizable-handle").hide();
    jQuery(".controls").hide();

});  


}
```

I am trying it in this way.Please help to solve the issue.

```
jQuery( "ul.get-image .resize-img" ).click(function( event ) {
      var $item = jQuery( this );
        //$target = jQuery( event.target );

        addImage( $item );

      return false;
});


function addImage( $item ) {

        var x = null;
        var x  = $item.clone();
        jQuery(".droppable .resize-img").removeClass("mycurrent");
        x.addClass("ui-draggable-dragging mycurrent ui-resizable");
        x.appendTo('.droppable');

        jQuery(".droppable .resize-img").css({"display":"inline-table"});
        /* To show Controls first time on Dragged Image*/
        var droppedItemId = x.attr("data-item-id");

        jQuery(".controls ").attr("controls-item-id",droppedItemId);
        jQuery(".droppable").find(".ui-resizable-handle").hide(); // To show Controls
        jQuery(".controls").show();

        var height = x.height();  // To show the controls with exact position
        var width = x.width(); //alert("stoppos"+stopPosition+"leftpos"+leftPos);
        var topPos = x.position().top;
        var leftPos = x.position().left;
        var mytop = topPos+height;
        var myleft = leftPos + width /2; 
        jQuery(".controls").css({"top": mytop , "left":myleft, "display":"block"});

        mydraggable(x); 

        myresizeable(x); 


}
```

Comment: Have you looked at this example ? https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager

Comment: Yes i have checked this. my drag and drop is working fine but i need to add click event also.when user will click on any image then it should be automatically dropped in dropable div.

Comment: See `function deleteImage( $item )` function from the above link.

Comment: I don't want to hide the image. Need to create clone of clicked image.

Comment: I can also provide the link where i am working on it.

Comment: Yeah please provide the link.

Comment: i have created a fiddle for this.This is link.  https://jsfiddle.net/webdev123/Lk60pprg/12/

Comment: as you can see on click images clone appends in the above div. But when you will try to resize it then it will not be resized and and 4 draggable handlers are not coming when you will try to drag the image. Please first check it with drag and drop and then on click of image.you will find my actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#droppable .controls li.canvas-remove-item', function (e) 
{
    var removeId = jQuery(".controls").attr("controls-item-id");
    //jQuery('#droppable .resize-img').filter('[data-item-id = '+removeId+']').remove();
    jQuery('#droppable .mycurrent').remove();   
    jQuery("#droppable").find(".ui-resizable-handle").hide();
    jQuery(".controls").hide();

});
```